# Is it possible to host a source code written website on joomla?

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla

I almost finished source code website for a client and he bought 3yrs hosting on joomla. I can't find a way to implement my code into joomla.

I searched for a custom CSS plugins and even tried to add custom blocks but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is a source code website? Joomla websites are only basic website usually on a LAMP stack. They are written with source code.

Comment: Problem is i already created website from scratch in VSCode and my client bought joomla hosting with CMS and I have no idea if its even possible to add my files there. Havent really worked with Joomla in my entire life so i dont even know what to think about this

Comment: Is it possible to convert my code somehow to be compatibile with joomla creator?

Comment: More details are necessary to answer this question. Of course, you could convert your code to a Joomla template, but that's much work and requires some knowledge about Joomla. Joomla supports static pages, but not whole websites. How does your client access the webspace? If they can upload static files, it should be possible to host your custom website.

Comment: This website has main page and 3 subpages if it matters. Not sure what you mean by webspace if you think about dashboard he simply writes url/admin and is redirected to login form. Dont know about static files to be honest I just started my journey and its my first client that i personally acquired and its my first time that i have to deal with domain and hosting. I'd love to provide all necessary information but i think i need more specific questions to be able to anwser them correctly

Comment: Stack Overflow is question and answer platform for specific questions. It doesn't work well for interactive debugging or discussion-like communication. This is not right platform for this question, but I also don't know other platforms. Maybe you can ask on Reddit or Quora.

Comment: I think that this fact might be important. So i cant access his hosting right now. I will be able to after he sends me soruces to work with because his page is still running right now  . For now I tried to setup joomla on localhost and I think that it may be limited(atleast i hope :|)

Answer (score 0):

Joomla 4 (or even 3) has Bootstrap integrated.
Any chance to upgrade the Joomla version if older?

Here a [Youtube Tutorial/Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qoWyXeEiTao).